# React-Native Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have this error on my Android emulator whenever I try to run my app with the firebase auth part. When I remove it's fine. What could be the issue here?

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
throwOnInvalidObjectType
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:9616:6
reconcileChildFibers
```

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase'
import { Header } from './components/common';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

class App extends Component {
    componentWilMount() {
        firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: 'AIzaSyB1eIxhsVkgc9FEv2iwAmbOWVL3ksKBENc',
            authDomain: 'authentication-47519.firebaseapp.com',
            databaseURL: 'https://authentication-47519.firebaseio.com',
            projectId: 'authentication-47519',
            storageBucket: 'authentication-47519.appspot.com',
            messagingSenderId: '823214787474'
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Header headerText="Authentication" />
                <LoginForm />
            </View>

        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

What could be the error here??

Comment: Which authentication do u use? google or email and password? and Is it only fail for emulator

Comment: email password, does not work on both actual device and emulator

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the component will mount method

```
componentWillMount(){

    !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: 'AIzaSyB1eIxhsVkgc9FEv2iwAmbOWVL3ksKBENc',
        authDomain: 'authentication-47519.firebaseapp.com',
        databaseURL: 'https://authentication-47519.firebaseio.com',
        projectId: 'authentication-47519',
        storageBucket: 'authentication-47519.appspot.com',
        messagingSenderId: '823214787474'
    }) : firebase.app();
   .......
```

add a method like this to call it

```
onLoginClicked() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword( email, password )
    .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
    .catch( () => {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword( email, password )
        .then(this.onRegisterSuccess.bind(this))
        .catch( (error) => {
            console.log(error.message);
        });
    });
     console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following these steps helped me solve that problem:

1. create a polyfills file code and put in a file named *polyfills.js*, at the same level with *index.js* (entry point of my react-native project)
2. the code:

```
global.Symbol = require('core-js/es6/symbol');
require('core-js/fn/symbol/iterator');
require('core-js/fn/map');
require('core-js/fn/set');
require('core-js/fn/array/find');
```

3. On the first line within *index.js* file include the following code:

```
import './polyfills.js';
```

Now Reload the app(Press R twice). Hope It works!

[Answer Reference](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js/issues/1305#issuecomment-454645846)